# Using OpenWRT to share Eduroam (802.1x) Wlan internet over the LAN plug

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, lan, openwrt

)

Have here rather conceptual questions regards a hypothetical *wisle* idea:
Take the eduroam Wlan Network (a 802.1x authentication one) and connect with a router (guess i have to flash openWRT) to it. Than share the precious internet to a device that does not have wireless but only a LAN plug (not extandable :( )

I understand more or less after googleling around, that OpenWRT is a good idea. That after flashing it on my tl-MR3020 i can connect in Client or Shared Ap mode to the Eduroam Network with it.

After that i have some questions: Do i just route the traffic from the Wlan to LAN? Would the device that gets the precious internet out of the Tplink router request it's own IP from the DHCP server of my Institute? Or would it use NAT to connect to the WWW world ?

Is it possible for the Administration to see that via my eduroam account a device is connected that shares the internet with a second device? And how would i access the second device over the internet? SSH to it? If so, how would i knew its IP address?

My understanding is rather poor, so would be happy about a good link! Not a network expert at all and know the question is rather simple ... Just to many new terms when reading the openWRT wiki. So maybe someone has a good explanation :) ?

thank you very much!